# can't login to mysql server with Vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant and building my dev environment and a bash script provisioning. This is the part that pertains to MySQL

```
echo "Preparing MySQL"
apt-get install debconf-utils -y > /dev/null
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password"

echo "Installing MySQL"
apt-get install mysql-server -y > /dev/null
```

when I ssh in with vagrant and run `mysql -u root -p` I get prompted for the password and put it in but it always says

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vagrant'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

I understand the error, but I'm new to Vagrant and working through the terminal really. What can I do to help identify and fix the problem?

In my Vagrantfile I am declaring `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.22.22.22"` if that makes any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the server version `mysql-server-5.5` instead of `mysql-server`.

After a first manual configuration you can often find all the manual provided configuration via `sudo debconf-get-selections`.

Beside this, you need to set the password in the command line:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password mypass"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password mypass"
sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y
```

The previous three commands work with Ubuntu 14.04, the mysql version can differ. The first part is always the package name.

Comment: is that just for the line under "Installing MySQL" or for the 2 lines under "Preparing MySQL" too?

Comment: I noticed when I load mysql I get this in the console `==> default: warning: Unknown type password1, skipping line 1
==> default: warning: Unknown type password1, skipping line 1`.

Comment: What is your command? For the three commands I listed above the command would be   `mysql -u root -pmypass`

I tested it with the three commands above and it works fine on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: it's when I'm using vagrant up to start the box. When I get to the installing of MySQL it outputs those lines. Which makes me think that the password is never set?